# How to take aggregated values from two different models and present them in the template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

models.py

```
# Customer Model

class Customer(models.Model):
    name =models.CharField(max_length=100)
    primary_contact = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    secondary_contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('customers')


# Issue Model

class Issue(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    kt = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.FloatField()
    vat = models.IntegerField(default=15)

@property
def kt_21(self):
    return round(self.kt / 21 * self.quantity , 2)

@property
def vat_amt(self):
    return self.quantity * self.rate * self.vat/100

@property
def total_amt(self):
    return self.quantity * self.rate + self.vat_amt

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('issue-hist')

def __str__(self):
    return  str(self.customer) + " - "+ str(self.total_amt)+' SAR'
# Receive Model

class Receive(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    kt = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.FloatField()
    vat = models.IntegerField(default=15)

    @property
    def kt_21(self):
        return round(self.kt / 21 * self.quantity , 2)
    
    @property
    def vat_amt(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate * self.vat/100

    @property
    def total_amt(self):
        return self.quantity * self.rate + self.vat_amt
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('rec-hist')

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.customer) + " - "+ str(self.total_amt)+' SAR'
```

I have these models, now what I want is to present the total quantity issued and received from a customer and the balance remaining. For that I tried to create a view which is as such

views.py(This is just one view from the file)

```
    class CustomerBalanceDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'customer/balances.html'
    context_object_name = 'cust'
    ordering = [Lower('name')]

    def balance(self, request, pk):
    

        custo = Customer.objects.get(id = pk)
        issue = Issue.objects.filter(customer = custo)
        tot = issue.aggregate(iss = Sum('quantity'))
                        
        return render(request, 'customer/balances.html',context={'total':tot.iss})
```

for now I have only tried to output the total issued amount, I tried using these queries in the shell and they worked but for some reason the context is not being passed in the template.

HTML template

```
{% extends 'base2.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load static%}

{% block css %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'utility.css' %}"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'customer/cust_d.css' %}"> 


{% endblock css %}



{% block content %}    

    <!-- Headers -->
    <h1 class="c_name h">Name</h1>
    <h1 class="cont h">Amount Issued</h1>
    <h1 class="s_cont h">Amount Received</h1>
    <h1 class="add h">Balance </h1>

    <!-- Product List -->
    <div class="flex-wrap">
        
            <div class="bar name">
                <p class="p1">{{cust.name}}</p>
                <p class="p2">{{total}}</p>

            </div>
        
    </div>

    <!-- Update & Delete Buttons -->


{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not to use a `class based view`. Just use the `function based view` and pass the context in the template with `"dot.nottaion"`.

Corrected files:

no change to models.py

`views.py`

```
def balance(request, pk):
    cust = Customer.objects.get(id = pk)

    # Calculating Issue
    issue = Issue.objects.filter(customer = cust)
    tot_issue = issue.aggregate(iss = Sum('quantity'))
    if tot_issue['iss'] == None:
        tot_issue['iss'] = 0

    # Calculating Receive
    receive = Receive.objects.filter(customer = cust)
    tot_receive = receive.aggregate(rec = Sum('quantity'))
    if tot_receive['rec'] == None:
        tot_receive['rec'] = 0

    # Calculating Balance
    balance = tot_issue['iss'] - tot_receive['rec']
    
    context={'cust':cust, 'total_i':tot_issue,'total_r':tot_receive, 'balance':balance }
    
    return render(request, 'customer/balances.html', context)
```

I removed the class view and now will have to manually query the customers name and all.

`HTML template`

```
{% extends 'base2.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load static%}

{% block css %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'utility.css' %}"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'customer/cust_d.css' %}"> 


{% endblock css %}



{% block content %}    

    <!-- Headers -->
    <h1 class="c_name h">Name</h1>
    <h1 class="cont h">Amount Issued</h1>
    <h1 class="s_cont h">Amount Received</h1>
    <h1 class="add h">Balance </h1>

    <!-- Product List -->
    <div class="flex-wrap">
        
            <div class="bar name">
                <p class="p1">{{cust.name}}</p>
                <p class="p2">{{total_i.iss}}</p>
                <p class="p3">{{total_r.rec}}</p>
                <p class="p4">{{balance}}</p>
            
            </div>
        
    </div>

    <!-- Update & Delete Buttons -->


{% endblock content %}
```